# Find a word and remove next x rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove some record from Excel spreadsheet. I want for macro to search for a certain name and upon finding a cell with that name, remove row containing it and next X rows.

So far I have a part that removes content of a cell upon certain words, but now I would need it to not clear but remove whole rows

```
Range("B2:H100").Replace What:="*Phone", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                         ReplaceFormat:=False

Range("B2:H100").Replace What:="*Queue", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                         ReplaceFormat:=False

Range("B2:H100").Replace What:="*2nd Line", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                         ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Use `Range.Find` instead of `Replace`. Then use `Resize` to grab that row and the next X rows.

Comment: Are these items found once or more than once?

Comment: No, it's like: find James and remove his row, and 7 below

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveRowsFindName()

Dim FindRng As Range
Dim xRows As Long
Dim FindWord As String

xRows = 7 ' number of extra rows to remove
FindWord = "Phone"

Set FindRng = Range("B2:H100").Find(What:=FindWord, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    Range("A" & FindRng.Row).Resize(1 + xRows, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
Else ' word not found in range
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & FindWord & " in range", vbCritical, "Find Error!"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shar Rado - 
This would be a part of a bit larger script designed for clearing out excel spreadsheet to be more transparent for HR team, I've pasted your suggesion as:

```
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim xRows As Long
Dim FindWord As String

xRows = 7
FindWord = "Tony"

Set FindRng = Range("B2:H100").Find(What:=FindWord, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then
    Range("A" & FindRng.Row).Resize(1 + xRows, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End If
```

But the overall macro did the same it done previously - didn't return any errors nor did the needed removal.